# Discord.py Leaving a server

Tags: python, discord.py

I dont have access to some of these test servers my bot is in and I want the bot to leave them, my code is

```
@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def guilds(ctx):
  await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
  guild = ""
  servers = bot.guilds
  for a in servers:
    guild += f"{a}\n"
    if a == "Fleshy's server":
      b = a.id()
      await bot.leave(b)
  await ctx.author.send(guild)
```

I dont get any error when i use this but it also doenst leave the Fleshy's servers
These are the servers he is in
`my server The Judas Cradle 7 test server yosh’s rock Fleshy's server Retronized Cafe Fleshy's server Fleshy's server Able's Hub`

Comment: So I did a few more test and its something with a.id, but if a would equal a guild wouldnt it be something like ctx.guild.id or like ctx.author.id, somewhat like that.
The test I ran was it would send me the id and i got nothing.

Comment: Do you have the IDs of the server?

Comment: No. I want the bot to leave a server that im not in.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to leave a guild by knowing its name you can run the following command:

```py
@bot.command()
async def leaveg(ctx, *, guild_name):
    guild = discord.utils.get(bot.guilds, name=guild_name) # Get the guild by name
    if guild is None:
        print("No guild with that name found.") # No guild found
        return
    await guild.leave() # Guild found
    await ctx.send(f"I left: {guild.name}!")
```

- We use `*` in order to also allow names with a space in it
- Import `from discord.utils import get`

If you know the ID of the server you can also run the following command:

```py
@bot.command()
async def leave(ctx, guild_id):
    await bot.get_guild(int(guild_id)).leave()
    await ctx.send(f"I left: {guild_id}")
```

- Import `from discord.utils import get`
- Make sure to put in the ID: `leave ServerID`

***You can also have a look at the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_guild).***

Comment: hmmm. This didnt work for me
`NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10004): Unknown Guild`
There was no print

Comment: The error is self-explanatory. Either you entered the name incorrectly or the server no longer exists/the ID is incorrect. (Depends on the method you use.)