# Issues with guild.leave [Discord.py]

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm attempting to create two commands that I can use to get my bot to leave servers, one that uses the bot's name, and the other that uses the guild ID. Here's the code:

```
@commands.command(name = "leaveguild", help="Used for debugging Guilds")
@commands.is_owner()
async def leaveguild(self, ctx, *, guild_name):
    sendback = bot.get_channel(923982936326418532)
    guild = discord.utils.get(bot.guilds, name=guild_name)
    if guild is None:
     print("No guild with that name found.")
     return
    await guild.leave()
    await ctx.send(f"I left: {guild.name}!")
    await sendback.send(f"I left: {guild.name}!")

@commands.command(name = "leaveid", help="Used for debugging IDs")
@commands.is_owner()
async def leaveid(self, ctx, guild_id):
  sendback = bot.get_channel(923982936326418532)
  await bot.get_guild(int(guild_id)).leave()
  await ctx.send(f"I left: {guild_id}")
  await sendback.send(f"I left: {guild_id}!")
```

Unfortunately, neither command works properly. The one using the name just prints `No guild with that name found`, despite me correctly inputting the name.
The one that uses ID on the other hand gives the error: `Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'leave'`

I don't know what I've been doing wrong, so I was wondering if anyone could possibly help.

Comment: This is my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66459211/discord-py-leaving-a-server) to another question. A `NoneType` error is spit out if something was not found/something does not exist. Try `await self.bot.get_guild(int(guild_id)).leave()` as it looks like you are using this in a `Cog`.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.